# Android O(8.0) access network or database cause native crash(HeapDaemonTask DeadLock)

Tags: android, crash, heap-memory, deadlock, android-8.0-oreo

I programming an app on Android Studio 2.3, which uses SQLite Databases and uploads data via an HTTP connection. Since I installed Android O on my Nexus 5X I have a problem. But Android N is no problem.

**Accessing a network or database on Android O, cause native crash.**

How can I solve this problem?
Someone please tell me the solution.

```
08-31 18:00:38.759 2221-2233/? A/zygote: verification.cc:102] GC tried to mark invalid reference 0x33
08-31 18:00:38.759 2221-2233/? A/zygote: verification.cc:102] ref=0x33 <invalid address>
08-31 18:00:38.759 2221-2233/? A/zygote: verification.cc:102] 
08-31 18:00:38.837 1523-1536/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492] Runtime aborting...
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492] Aborting thread:
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=5 tid=8 WaitingPerformingGc
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13041650 self=0xa29ae800
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | sysTid=2233 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x93903970
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | state=R schedstat=( 1293422132 461940771 1717 ) utm=91 stm=38 core=0 HZ=100
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | stack=0x93801000-0x93803000 stackSize=1038KB
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #00 pc 0047358b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+203)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #01 pc 0056ee2e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+366)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #02 pc 005696b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+83)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #03 pc 0054dff7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+55)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #04 pc 0054ddaa  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+490)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #05 pc 0053b4ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+189)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #06 pc 0053bf69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime7AborterEPKc+41)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #07 pc 0011c1d3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIPFvPKcENS_9allocatorIS5_EES4_EclEOS3_+35)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #08 pc 00650d10  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD1Ev+1152)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #09 pc 002d4fa7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art2gc12Verification17LogHeapCorruptionENS_6ObjPtrINS_6mirror6ObjectEEENS_12MemberOffsetEPS4_b+1687)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #10 pc 00257b0a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying13MarkNonMovingEPNS_6mirror6ObjectES5_NS_12MemberOffsetE+410)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #11 pc 0025a7f8  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying7ProcessEPNS_6mirror6ObjectENS_12MemberOffsetE+376)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #12 pc 00259f31  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6mirror6Object15VisitReferencesILb1ELNS_17VerifyObjectFlagsE0ELNS_17ReadBarrierOptionE1ENS_2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying16RefFieldsVisitorES8_EEvRKT2_RKT3_+481)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #13 pc 00252374  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying19ProcessMarkStackRefEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+148)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #14 pc 00251abc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying20ProcessMarkStackOnceEv+684)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #15 pc 002517eb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying16ProcessMarkStackEv+43)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #16 pc 0024a024  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying12MarkingPhaseEv+740)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #17 pc 00249060  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying9RunPhasesEv+736)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #18 pc 00262493  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector16GarbageCollector3RunENS0_7GcCauseEb+451)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #19 pc 0028f7a4  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22CollectGarbageInternalENS0_9collector6GcTypeENS0_7GcCauseEb+4484)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #20 pc 002a10b0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap12ConcurrentGCEPNS_6ThreadENS0_7GcCauseEb+128)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #21 pc 002ab425  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap16ConcurrentGCTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+53)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #22 pc 002d419b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+59)
08-31 18:00:38.924 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #23 pc 00480997  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL22VMRuntime_runHeapTasksEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+55)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #24 pc 00213e08  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (???)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:461)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492] All threads:
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492] DALVIK THREADS (79):
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=5 tid=8 Runnable
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13041650 self=0xa29ae800
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | sysTid=2233 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x93903970
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | state=R schedstat=( 1317052733 467894200 1737 ) utm=91 stm=40 core=0 HZ=100
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | stack=0x93801000-0x93803000 stackSize=1038KB
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #00 pc 0047358b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+203)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #01 pc 0056ee2e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+366)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #02 pc 005696b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+83)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #03 pc 0058be4a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+1210)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #04 pc 005824aa  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureES2_+570)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #05 pc 00581dae  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+958)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #06 pc 0054e203  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState14DumpAllThreadsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+355)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #07 pc 0054ddbc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+508)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #08 pc 0053b4ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+189)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #09 pc 0053bf69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime7AborterEPKc+41)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #10 pc 0011c1d3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIPFvPKcENS_9allocatorIS5_EES4_EclEOS3_+35)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #11 pc 00650d10  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD1Ev+1152)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #12 pc 002d4fa7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art2gc12Verification17LogHeapCorruptionENS_6ObjPtrINS_6mirror6ObjectEEENS_12MemberOffsetEPS4_b+1687)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #13 pc 00257b0a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying13MarkNonMovingEPNS_6mirror6ObjectES5_NS_12MemberOffsetE+410)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #14 pc 0025a7f8  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying7ProcessEPNS_6mirror6ObjectENS_12MemberOffsetE+376)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #15 pc 00259f31  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6mirror6Object15VisitReferencesILb1ELNS_17VerifyObjectFlagsE0ELNS_17ReadBarrierOptionE1ENS_2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying16RefFieldsVisitorES8_EEvRKT2_RKT3_+481)
08-31 18:00:38.925 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #16 pc 00252374  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying19ProcessMarkStackRefEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+148)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #17 pc 00251abc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying20ProcessMarkStackOnceEv+684)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #18 pc 002517eb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying16ProcessMarkStackEv+43)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #19 pc 0024a024  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying12MarkingPhaseEv+740)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #20 pc 00249060  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying9RunPhasesEv+736)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #21 pc 00262493  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector16GarbageCollector3RunENS0_7GcCauseEb+451)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #22 pc 0028f7a4  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22CollectGarbageInternalENS0_9collector6GcTypeENS0_7GcCauseEb+4484)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #23 pc 002a10b0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap12ConcurrentGCEPNS_6ThreadENS0_7GcCauseEb+128)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #24 pc 002ab425  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap16ConcurrentGCTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+53)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #25 pc 002d419b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+59)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #26 pc 00480997  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL22VMRuntime_runHeapTasksEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+55)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   native: #27 pc 00213e08  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+104)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:461)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
08-31 18:00:38.926 2221-2233/? A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]
```

.

```
08-28 16:17:41.783 3305-3321/com.mypackage A/zygote: runtime.cc:500] GC tried to mark invalid reference 0x1a4
08-28 16:17:41.783 3305-3321/com.mypackage A/zygote: runtime.cc:500] ref=0x1a4 <invalid address>
08-28 16:17:41.783 3305-3321/com.mypackage A/zygote: runtime.cc:500] holder=0x13880000 klass=0x704a1048(java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object[]>) length=131069 space=main space (region space) 0x12c00000-0x52c00000 card=0 adjacent_ram=00000000000000000000000000000000|48104a7000000010fdff010020069413field_offset=262208
08-28 16:17:41.783 3305-3321/com.mypackage A/zygote: runtime.cc:500] 
08-28 16:17:41.878 3633-3321/? A/google-breakpad: Microdump skipped (uninteresting)
08-28 16:17:41.903 3305-3321/com.mypackage A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3321 (HeapTaskDaemon)
08-28 16:17:42.088 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-28 16:17:42.088 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/bullhead/bullhead:8.0.0/OPR6.170623.013/4283548:user/release-keys'
08-28 16:17:42.088 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG: Revision: 'rev_1.0'
08-28 16:17:42.088 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
08-28 16:17:42.089 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG: pid: 3305, tid: 3321, name: HeapTaskDaemon  >>> com.mypackage <<<
08-28 16:17:42.089 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
08-28 16:17:42.102 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'utils.cc:123] 12c00000-52c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 13910                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space) (deleted)'
08-28 16:17:42.102 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00000cf9  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
08-28 16:17:42.102 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG:     r4 00000ce9  r5 00000cf9  r6 d8786a90  r7 0000010c
08-28 16:17:42.102 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG:     r8 0000000b  r9 d8786af1  sl 0000000a  fp d8786af0
08-28 16:17:42.102 3642-3642/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000000  sp d8786a80  lr f3df73b7  pc f3e2791c  cpsr 200f0010
```

Comment: I have been facing similar issues on the Nexus 6P. Were you able to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Someone registered the issue in the issue tracker and I expect it to be resolved. - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65147194

Comment: Has anyone fixed this? @lmklmk99 Did you succeed in making some workaround or something?

Comment: @MateKrižanac Google  release the new SDK 8.1 to resolve the issue. you can check it 
 here. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37187694

Comment: Thanks for the reply @lmklmk99, I can see the issue and I found it here https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/art/+/430379/ , but update on my phone with 8.0 still didn't receive it I think, considering it is still crashing same as before.

Comment: Thanks lmklmk99 for updates. it really saved a lot of time.